# How to: Find the best result depending on different variables (Brute-Force)

Tags: java, function, math, brute-force

I have the following variables:

```
int n = 0   //with an range from 10 - 200 and a increment of 1
int f = 0       //with an range from 0 - 7    and a increment of 1
double g = 0.0  //with an range from -10.0 - 10.0 and a increment of 0.001
double h = 0.0  //with an range from -10.0 - 10.0 and a increment of 0.001
double k = 0.0. //with an range from -5.0 - 5.0 and a increment of 0.1
```

Now I have got the following program structure in Java:

```
private
int result = 0;

    forLoopNr1(){   

        //...
        //functions based on the variables: n 
        //...

        forLoopNr2(){   

        //...
        //functions based on the variables: f, g, h, k
        //...

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

For the moment I change the variables bye hand and treat them more like a constant. Any 
change in the variables in the given range with the given increment affects the outcome.
The problem is, that I search for the highest result and can't try every possibility.
(result = n * f * g * h * k) and its not that simple that the best result is based on the highest values.

To me, it looks similar to a combination lock. So the Brute-Force algorithm would be a possible clue.

What I need is some kind of loop that change the variables to make sure every possibility is tried.
like:

```
private
int result = 0;

variableChangingLoop(){ 
    //changes n,f,g,h,k in order that every possibility is taken bevore loop is done

    forLoopNr1(){       

        //...
        //functions based on the variables: n 
        //...

        forLoopNr2(){   

        //...
        //functions based on the variables: f, g, h, k
        //...

        }
    }

    return result;
    }
}
```

I hope its clear. I try to keep this example as simple as possible.

My solution so far:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double g = -10.0;
        double h = -10.0;
        double k = -10.0;
        int f = 1;
        int n = 10;

        int counter = 0;

        try
        {
            while (n <= 200)
            {
                g = g + 0.1;

                if (g >= 10.0)
                {
                    g = -10.0;
                    h = h + 0.01;
                }

                if (h >= 10.0)
                {
                    h = -10.0;
                    k = k + 0.01;
                }

                if (k >= 10.0)
                {
                    k = -10.0;
                    f = f + 1;
                }

                if (f >= 7)
                {
                    f = 1;
                    n =  +1;
                }

                //here space for calculations and other functions

            }


        }

        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My question, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but why not put all the numbers in a list and sort it?

Comment: @whirlwin OP is asking to find the n, f, g, h and k for which `n * f * g * h * k` is maximum (I think)

Comment: I don't really understand your question.... If the result = n * f * g * h * k, wouldn't maximising all of them (positively) give you the maximum value? (I.E. 200 * 7 * 10.0 * 10.0 * 5.0).

Comment: This looks like a homework question only we're missing a good three quarters of the context.

Comment: Right. There are a lot of calculationfunctions in the loops depending on the value in the variables. All the calculation are based on different datasets. So its not that simpel that the highest result is based on the highest value in the variables.

Comment: ...in that case, we are missing a ton of information which we need to help you with. Could you supply that, then?

Comment: I added some information to my question. Hope that make it clearer now.